# Is there a way to get Firefox language to stay on my choice?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, spell-checking

Periodically, I get a spell check underline that indicates I misspelled a word.  Usually, it is something I can spell like "color". When I check the language, it often shows "English UK", "English Canada" or "English Australia".  I would like to delete those other languages altogether.  I leave it default on "English USA" but it still moves around at random.

Comment: When you have Check Spelling enabled and then right click in a text box, next to "Languages" can you see the languages you listed, including English (United States)? Are you saying "English (United States)" is selected but spell checking is by UK dictionary? Or is the selected language changing on its own? (I am using FF 38.0 and 14.04 for reference if it matters).

Answer (score 0):

Go to addons, then select "languages" on the left, then delete everything on the right. American English should be included in Firefox. (Or at least it is if your system language is American English.)

Comment: Thank you, 
I looked in the languages, but there are English GB and English South Africa, both disabled, and nothing else there.  No English UK, Canada or Australia.  I guess I am just stuck with it.  

Thanks for your answer, it looked like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the spelling check option that is set by default. Go to browser *preferences*-->*advanced*-->*general* and unmark *"check my spelling as I type"* (*see the screenshot*) and restart the browser.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the option, but I think I'll pass on that one.  I'd rather learn to spell with an accent than give up my spell check, LOL.

Comment: you can check the spelling back any time you need just *right click* while you type and mark *check spelling* ;) it just will stop annoying you by default option as it sets itself.